# InfoWindow contents spilling out using dynamic template?

Tags: google-fusion-tables, infowindow

Can anyone tell my why the contents of my InfoWindows are spilling out? When I view the InfoWindows in the Fusion Table UI, they all pop up and resize themselves correctly:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?q=select+col7+from+15wosKAeHC0gcpU_N6UPbxPL09RrEBKlQNEaCmnU&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=34.199813229302734&lng=-111.2955847411987&t=1&z=8&l=col7&y=2&tmplt=2

But when I try to use the html code to create a webpage, some (not all) of the InfoWindow contents spill out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CaveCreek - Google Fusion Tables</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body, #googft-mapCanvas {
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.199813229302734, -111.2955847411987),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
      query: {
        select: "col7",
        from: "15wosKAeHC0gcpU_N6UPbxPL09RrEBKlQNEaCmnU",
        where: ""
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      }
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My dynamic template InfoWindow code looks like:

```
{template .contents}
<div>
  <div style="align: center">
    <b>{$data.value.Stream}</b>
  </div>
{if $data.value.y2012}
<a href="{$data.value.y2012}" target="_blank">2012</a>-{/if}
{if $data.value.y2012a}
<a href="{$data.value.y2012a}" target="_blank">2012a</a>-{/if}
...
</div>
{/template}
```

I have tried to add height and width to the div tag for the InfoWindow in the template but that still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the visualRefresh, that is causing the infoWindow size to be calculated incorrectly.

```
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Google Maps visual refresh is going to be the default soon, so removing it is not a long-term solution.

If you set the height of the div and add overflow-y: scroll you should get a scrollbar on your content; does that not happen? One of the examples in the dynamic template help is setting the height differently based on fields being there or not, so that might help.